# Combine data from different rows from msqli query in PHP into a single json object

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables:

**Packets**

[image]

**Measurements**

[image]

I am trying to make a json object out of the the msqli query but am failing misearbly.
The query:

`select * from packets p left join measurements m ON p.id = m.packet_id`

which results in the following table:

[image]

Out of this I would like to create the following json objects in PHP:

```
{
    "packet": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "pi_id": 0,
            "rcv_counter": 6,
            "rcv_RSSI": -64,
            "tag_id": 1,
            "measurement": {
                "measurement1": 123,
                "measurement2": 456
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "pi_id": 0,
            "rcv_counter": 144,
            "rcv_RSSI": -64,
            "measurement": {
                "measurement1": 456,
                "measurement2": 789
            }
    ]
}
```

With my current code I do not know how to iterate over the inner 2 measurements:

```
if ($result != NULL) {

        while ($resulthead = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $resulthead["id"];
        $tmp["pi_id"] = $resulthead["pi_id"];
        $tmp["rcv_counter"] = $resulthead["rcv_counter"];
        $tmp["rcv_RSSI"] = $resulthead["rcv_RSSI"];
        $tmp["tag_id"] = $resulthead["tag_id"];

            array_push($response["tag"], $tmp);
}
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
$output = [];
if ($result !== null) {
    while ($resulthead = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (isset($output[$resulthead['packet_id']])) {
            $count = count($output[$resulthead['packet_id']]['measurement']) + 1;
            $output[$resulthead['packet_id']]['measurement']["measurement{$count}"] = $resulthead['measurement'];
        } else {
            $output[$resulthead['packet_id']] = [
                'id' => $resulthead["id"],
                'pi_id' => $resulthead["pi_id"],
                'rcv_counter' => $resulthead["rcv_counter"],
                'rcv_RSSI' => $resulthead["rcv_RSSI"],
                'tag_id' => $resulthead["tag_id"],
                'measurement' => [
                    'measurement1' => $resulthead['measurement'],
                ],
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 Stars, Your untested code worked like a charm. I adjusted the code a bit to get to the format I needed. Thanks for teaching me a bit more about PHP.